# Change notification text when bot sends an adaptive card in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am developing a bot with microsoft BotFramework.When bot sends an adaptive card the notification text is "Sent a Card".

Is there a way to modify this text?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change notification Text for adaptive cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64983584/change-notification-text-for-adaptive-cards)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can change the text on the notification using "Summary" property of an activity.
You can go ahead and try out this sample code:

```
var response = MessageFactory.Text(string.Empty);

AdaptiveCard ad = new AdaptiveCard();
ad.Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>() {
new AdaptiveTextBlock()
{
Text= "testing",
Id ="testing"
}
};
Attachment att = new Attachment()
{
Content=ad,
ContentType= AdaptiveCard.ContentType
};
response.Attachments.Add(att);

response.Summary = "showing custom greeeting from the Bot - rather than send a card";
context.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
```